# waiting for keyboard input

Tags: android, user-input

I'm writing an app using Android 2.1
At some point, I call setOnKeyListener
In particular, I write...

```
  editfield=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
  editfield.setOnKeyListener(this);
```

This is in the main thread, in the onCreate callback.
At this point in the code, I would like the processing to stop and wait for the
keyboard input.  If I let the code run on, the logic will break, soon enough.

I suppose I could put the machine in a wait loop until a keystroke invokes the onClick method.  I could also create a wait loop at the point where the input from the user was required.  But I don't feel comfortable with either of these solutions.  (A related problem is this -- at a certain point in the code, the screen must be lit up.  Must I check this before proceeding past that point?

Perhaps I'm not good with documentation, but I have not been able to find anything specific that answers these questions.

Can someone explain to me how to accomplish the timing I need and, more generaly, where I can find info on these questions?

Thanks in advance.

-looking in DC

Answer (score 2):

The Android key system is event-based, it does not work like the old ask-and-wait mechanisms of C/C++ etc for obtaining user input.

If you blocked/waited - then what would happen if the user pressed the Home key (you can't catch that) or navigated to another app - your app would force close because it would still be waiting and your `onPause` etc would not execute.

My suggestion would be:

1. Put all the code that should occur after the click into some function
2. Place the listener at the end of `onCreate`, this way no more code will be executed after you set the listener
3. When you get a key-down, call your function. Thus the statements in your function will only execute *after* a key down

If however, this is for a game, then it is acceptable to have a thread dedicated to touch/key-events which sleeps for 50s or so to avoid event overload (but this must not be the main UI thread!)